# How to select with sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js, discord.js

I want to select a row from my database using Sequelize.
But when i'm doing it, there is no data even if it exists in the database.
And when i'm trying with a "findAll", without the "where" i can get all the data.

It is maybe a problem with my model ? Or a bad understanding of how Sequelize works ?

Thx for your help !

```
 static startLookingForAWar (args, message, teamModel) {
     if (args.length == 1) {
         var currentSecretKey = args[0]
         var teamName = null
         var teamClanTagInGame = null
         var teamLookForAWar = null
         teamModel.findOne({
             where: {
                 secretKey: currentSecretKey
             }
         }).then(response => {
             console.log(response)
         }).catch(error => {
             console.log(error)
             message.author.send("Something went wrong")            
         })
         if (teamName != null && teamClanTagInGame != null && teamLookForAWar != null) {
             if (teamLookForAWar) {
                 message.author.send("You are already in matchmaking lookin for a war !")
                 return
             }
             message.author.send("matchmaking activated !  GL !")
         }
     }
     else {
         message.author.send('Mhhhhh i think something is missing in your request !')
     }
 }
```

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")

module.exports =  (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define("team", {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            field: "id",
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            field : "name"
        },
        clanTagInGame: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
            field: "clanTagInGame"
        },
        leaderTag: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            field: "leaderTag"
        },
        secretKey: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            field: "secretKey",
            unique: true
        },
        lookingForAWar: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
            field: "lookingForAWar"
        },
        elo: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            field: "elo"
        },
        win: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            field: "win"
        },
        loose: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            field: "loose"
        }

    }, {
        tableName: 'team'
    })
}
```

Crayzze

**EDIT**
I have found the problem, it was because in my database some data were wrong with one blank space before every `string` ^^

Comment: could you put the entire function you are using for the `.findOne()` method?

Comment: Yes of course, i will update my post

Comment: You are not using promises correctly - some of your code is executing before the queries complete (the query results are in `.then()`. Look into using `async/await` to make the structure more intuitive.

Comment: @doublesharp I have to put the ```await``` just before the ```.teamModel.findOne()``` or somewhere else ?

Comment: the function would need to be marked as `async` and then you can resolve promises values like this `const response = await teamModel.findOne({ where: { secretKey: currentSecretKey } });`

Comment: Ok i fixed this, but i have a null return, i think it cannot find the good row in the database with this secretKey. But in the database there is a row with this correct field. I don't understand why, this is probably a problem with my model ? @doublesharp

Comment: So i have something new. When i replace ```secretKey: currentSecretKey``` by ```id: 1```, i have the good row. But i want to get it with the secretKey value.
Do you have any suggest ? The only field that is working is the ```id```